# Angular: Read all Environment variables

Tags: angular

**THE CASE**

I need to build a configuration service in my Angular project.

The service has to do the following tasks:

1. Read all predefined params from "environment" file
2. Get any additional params from any component
3. Of course provide params to any component

**THE SAMPLE**

I tried to do this:

```js
for(let key in environment)
{
    console.log(key);
    console.log(environment[key]);
}
```

**THE ERROR**

And I got the error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
> 'string' can't be used to index type '{ production: boolean; }'.

> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{
> production: boolean; }'.ts(7053)

**THE QUESTION**

How to read all params from environment file with a loop or similar?

I don't want to "hardcode" param names which shall be taken from the "environment" file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try

```
for (let [key, val] of Object.entries(environment)) {
  console.log(key, val)
}
```

You can check [MDN's Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Comment: @Centry Thanks! I tried something similar but not exactly this way.